# How to change type from OpaquePointer to my Data Model variable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create an array of Categories, which for me is a data model entity that has a 'name' attribute. However, Xcode sets it to an OpaquePointer, which is not what I want and is causing a bunch of errors. How do I force it to be of type Category rather than OpaquePointer? [image][image]

Answer (score 2):

You're having a collision with the [ObjC type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/category#) of the same name. I recommend changing the name of your type. Otherwise you're going to need to add your module name (`MyModule.Category`) a lot to remove the ambiguity.